# Why does this component re-render completely when changing a single item with a unique key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a reoccurring problem for me… Trying to figure out why an update to a single item in a component results in the entire component re-rendering. If I have a CSS fade in transition on the component, it fades in again when changing a child of the component.

---

I have a list of items, each with a link. Clicking the link adds the item to the cart. I have it set up to put that item in a “loading” state until the cart action is successful.

This used to work perfectly, but now it just re-renders the entire page, making it disappear for a second then reappear. I’m not entirely sure why.

This is the code stripped down to its basic bits:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import autobind from 'class-autobind';

import Responsive from 'components/Responsive';

// Selectors
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { selectCartLoading, selectCartMap, selectFavorites } from 'containers/App/selectors';
import { selectPackages } from 'store/fonts/selectors';

// Actions
import { addToCart } from 'containers/App/actions';

export class Packages extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    autobind(this);
  }

  state = {
    loadingID: 0
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.cartLoading === true && nextProps.cartLoading === false) {
      this.setState({ loadingID: 0 });
    }
  }

  onAddToCart(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { onAddToCart } = this.props;
    const id = e.currentTarget.dataset.package;

    const packageData = {
      type: 'package',
      id,
      quantity: 1
    };

    onAddToCart(packageData);

    this.setState({ loadingID: id });
  }

  render() {
    const { cartMapping, packages } = this.props;

    if (!packages) { return null; }

    return (
      <Responsive>
        <div>
          <ul>
            { packages.map((pack) => {
              const inCart = !!cartMapping[parseInt(pack.id, 10)];
              const isFavorited = !favorites ? false : !!find(favorites.favorites, (favorite) => parseInt(pack.id, 10) === favorite.items.id);

              return (
                <li key={ pack.id }>
                  <Icon iconName="heart" onClick={ (e) => this.onAddFavorite(e, pack) } />
                  <span>{ pack.name }</span>
                  { inCart && <span>In Cart</span> }
                  { !inCart && <a data-package={ pack.id } href="/" onClick={ this.onAddToCart }>Add to Cart</a> }
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </Responsive>
    );
  }
}

Packages.propTypes = {
  cartLoading: PropTypes.bool,
  cartMapping: PropTypes.object,
  onAddToCart: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  packages: PropTypes.array
};

Packages.defaultProps = {
  cartLoading: null,
  cartMapping: null,
  packages: null
};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  cartLoading: selectCartLoading(),
  cartMapping: selectCartMap(),
  packages: selectPackages()
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onAddToCart: (data) => dispatch(addToCart(data)),
    dispatch
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Packages);
```

So why does clicking on `<a data-package={ pack.id } href="/" onClick={ this.onAddToCart }>Add to Cart</a>` result in a complete component re-render?

Comment: `setState` will cause a rerender. Looks like you're not using `loadingID`. Comment out `this.setState({ loadingID: id });`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onAddToCart` function you are setting the state of the component which will by default trigger a re-render of the component. If you need to set the state but not cause a re-render you can add a `shouldComponentUpdate()` function and check the changes before issuing a re-render to the component.

Find out more about `shouldComponentUpdate()` and the rest of the [component lifecycle here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Comment: It’s the flash I’m so curious about. One menu renders, second menu finishes setup and renders, first menu disappears and reappears for a split second. It’s… ugly, and I can’t figure it out.